# Issues with .dt and daylight changes in Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas-groupby

I would like to sum across a month on a certain column. Since I have many months, I separate per month. It works fine before 31th of October 2021 and also when I make separate data set after 31th of October.

Currently my date column looks like this:

```
2021-10-31T01:59:52+02:00
```

and like this:

```
2021-10-31T02:00:02+01:00
```

My code looks like this:

```
df_merged['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_merged['Time'])

df_ny5=df_merged.groupby(df_merged['Time'].dt.strftime('%B'))['ApcUptime_Evap'].mean().sort_values()
```

And I get the following error when I compile the code on the complete data set:

Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values.

Comment: since you have mixed UTC offsets in your 'Time' column, the data type of the whole Series will be object - that's how pandas datetime handles mixed time zones or UTC offsets. What you can do is convert to UTC; `df_merged['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_merged['Time'], utc=True)`, then set a time zone, e.g. `df_merged['Time'] = df_merged['Time'].dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin')`. Europe/Berlin is just an example, it has UTC+1 (DST inactive) and UTC+2 (DST active).